# I am unable to click save button on print preview popup. Destination value selected but unable to click save button

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image: Image is attached by using mentioned code i am able to select value from destination dropdown but unable to click on save button]Used code

```
        driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandles().toArray()[1].toString());
        // Select Save as pdf From the Dropdown.
        WebElement dropdown= (WebElement) executor.executeScript("return document.querySelector('print-preview-app').shadowRoot.querySelector('print-preview-sidebar').shadowRoot.querySelector('print-preview-destination-settings').root.querySelector('print-preview-destination-select').root.querySelector('select.md-select');");

        Select select = new Select(dropdown); 

        // Select Save as Pdf Option
        select.selectByValue("Save as PDF/local/");
        logger.info("Value selected");
```

// Till here code is working

```
        **Thread.sleep(4000);
        executor.executeScript("return document.querySelector('print-preview-app').shadowRoot.querySelector('print-preview-sidebar').shadowRoot.querySelector('print-preview-button-strip').shadowRoot.querySelector('cr-button.action-button').click();");**
```

The issue is on finding the element with Javascript executor

```
 executeScript("return document.querySelector('print-preview-app').shadowRoot.querySelector('print-preview-sidebar').shadowRoot.querySelector('print-preview-button-strip').shadowRoot.querySelector('cr-button.action-button').click();")
```

Comment: paste the HTML snippet you are trying to access and the URL you are using in order to help you to solve your issue